# How come the collision detection only works sometimes?

Tags: java, android, collision-detection

I am creating an android app and I am creating a game and the droid has to be able to bounce off the walls and the edge of the screen. Here is my update method in my MainGamePanel.java file where I call the collision detection.
It works when it just has to bounce off the edge of the screen. However when I try to get it bounce off the wall objects it sometimes works. When it doesn't, it goes through the wall sometimes, although this only happens when it moves up and down. It also sometimes gets stuck in the wall. How would I modify the collision detection so I won't have these issues. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
public void update() 
{
    // check collision with right wall if heading right
    if (droid.getSpeed().getxDirection() == Speed.DIRECTION_RIGHT
            && droid.getX() + droid.getBitmap().getWidth() / 2 >= getWidth()) {
        droid.getSpeed().toggleXDirection();

    }
    // check collision with left wall if heading left
    else if (droid.getSpeed().getxDirection() == Speed.DIRECTION_LEFT
            && droid.getX() - droid.getBitmap().getWidth() / 2 <= 0) {
        droid.getSpeed().toggleXDirection();
        droid.getSpeed().setYv(0);
    }
    // check collision with bottom wall if heading down
    else if (droid.getSpeed().getyDirection() == Speed.DIRECTION_DOWN
            && droid.getY() + droid.getBitmap().getHeight() / 2 >= getHeight()) {
        droid.getSpeed().toggleYDirection();
        droid.getSpeed().setXv(0);
    }
    // check collision with top wall if heading up
    else if (droid.getSpeed().getyDirection() == Speed.DIRECTION_UP
            && droid.getY() - droid.getBitmap().getHeight() / 2 <= 0) {
        droid.getSpeed().toggleYDirection();
        droid.getSpeed().setXv(0);
    }

    for (int i = 0 ; i < listOfWs.length ; i++)
    {
        if (droid.getX() +(droid.getBitmap().getWidth()/2)+1 > listOfWs [i].giveLeft ()
                && droid.getX()-(droid.getBitmap().getWidth()/2)-1 < listOfWs [i].giveRight () 
                && droid.getY()+(droid.getBitmap().getHeight()/2)+1 > listOfWs [i].giveTop ()
                && droid.getY()-(droid.getBitmap().getHeight()/2)-1 < listOfWs [i].giveBottom () )
        {
            if(droid.getSpeed().getYv()==0){
                droid.getSpeed().toggleXDirection();//Takes the speed and multiplies it by -1 so it changes direction   
            }
            else{
                droid.getSpeed().toggleYDirection();    
            }
        }

    }
    // Update the lone droid
    droid.update();
}
```

Here is my droid.java file that I used.

```
public class Droid {
    private Bitmap bitmap; // the actual bitmap
    private int x;   // the X coordinate
    private int y;   // the Y coordinate
    public Speed speed;

    public Droid(Bitmap bitmap, int x, int y) {
         this.bitmap = bitmap;
         this.x = x;
         this.y = y;
         speed= new Speed();
    }
    public Bitmap getBitmap() {
         return bitmap;
    }
    public void setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        this.bitmap = bitmap;
    }
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, x - (bitmap.getWidth() /2), y - (bitmap.getHeight() / 2), null);
    }

    public void update() {
        x += (int)(speed.getXv() * speed.getxDirection());
        y += (int)(speed.getYv() * speed.getyDirection());
    }

    public Speed getSpeed(){
        return speed;
    }
}
```

This is the speed.java file.

```
public class Speed {

    public static final int DIRECTION_RIGHT = 4;
    public static final int DIRECTION_LEFT  = -4;
    public static final int DIRECTION_UP    = -4;
    public static final int DIRECTION_DOWN  = 4;

    private float xv = 1;   // velocity value on the X axis
    private float yv = 1;   // velocity value on the Y axis

    private int xDirection = DIRECTION_RIGHT;
    private int yDirection = DIRECTION_DOWN;

    public Speed() {
        this.xv = 1;
        this.yv = 1;
    }
    public Speed(float xv, float yv) {
        this.xv = xv;
        this.yv = yv;
    }

    public float getXv() {
        return xv;
    }

    public void setXv(float xv) {
        this.xv = xv;
    }

    public float getYv() {
        return yv;
    }

    public void setYv(float yv) {
        this.yv = yv;
    }

    public int getxDirection() {
        return xDirection;
    }

    public void setxDirection(int xDirection) {
        this.xDirection = xDirection;
    }

    public void setRight() {
        xDirection = DIRECTION_RIGHT;
    }

    public void setLeft() {
        xDirection = DIRECTION_LEFT;
    }
    public void setUp() {
        yDirection = DIRECTION_UP;
    }
    public void setDown() {
        yDirection = DIRECTION_DOWN;
    }

    public int getyDirection() {
        return yDirection;
    }

    public void setyDirection(int yDirection) {
        this.yDirection = yDirection;
    }

    // changes the direction on the X axis
    public void toggleXDirection() {
        xDirection = xDirection * -1;
    }

    // changes the direction on the Y axis
    public void toggleYDirection() {
        yDirection = yDirection * -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in the update method, in for circulation, it seems you make your logical operation there, would you make it more specific?

Comment: How would I make it more specific?